# How to set footer height same as items in LazyRow?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a few a list of items, I want to attach a footer to it. The content of items is different from footer and that is why they have different heights.

```kotlin
LazyRow() {
    items(myList) { item ->
           RowItem(item)
    }
    item {
           Footer()
    }
}
```

I want the footer to be of the same height as other items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by getting height of `RowItem` using `Modifier.onSizeChanged`, assuming all of your items have same same height, then after converting height in Int to Dp and set it as height of your `Footer`

Here is an example with `LazyRow`

```
@Composable
private fun DynamicFooterList() {
    var height by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    val density = LocalDensity.current

    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(count=5) { item ->
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier.onSizeChanged {
                    if (height == 0.dp) {
                        height = with(density) { it.height.toDp() }
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Column {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape5_before),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                        text = "Image inside Card",
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        item {
            Box(
                modifier = (if (height > 0.dp) Modifier.height(height) else Modifier).then(
                    Modifier.background(
                        Color.LightGray, CutCornerShape(8.dp)
                    )
                ),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text("A liitle long Footer", fontSize = 20.sp)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a conditional Modifier for `RowItem` if you want to not check size after height is 0.dp but don't know if it would have any effect on performance

[image]