# How to set last item height same as items in the LazyRow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

Hey folks,
This is one interesting topic i believe, if we create a **LazyRow** with a specific height components, and i have another **item** which i need the same height of the **LazyRow** item. I have read [How to set footer height same as items in LazyRow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124098/how-to-set-footer-height-same-as-items-in-lazyrow), but feel there should be some another mechanism to achieve this, curious to know.

```kotlin
LazyRow() {
                            items(data) {
                                Column(
                                    modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.DarkGray)
                                        .padding(16.dp)
                                ) {
                                    Text(
                                        text = it,
                                        color = Color.White
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                            item {
                                Column(
                                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.DarkGray)
                                ) {
                                    Button(
                                        onClick = {
                                        }
                                    ) {
                                        Text(
                                            text = "Submit"
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: I have upvoted @Thracian's answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Modifier.size(100.dp)` to `Column` modifier inside `item` works

```kotlin
LazyRow() {
        items(data) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.DarkGray)
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = it,
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }
        }
        item {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.DarkGray)
            ) {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Submit"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]